# Show that $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x}dx = \int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x}dx = \int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}dx$

I tried finding anti-derivatives but it doesn't seem simple at all.

I'm not sure if I should try to calculate them separately or somehow show they converge to the same value.

Looking for a small hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). In particular, $u = \frac{1}{1 + x} = (1 + x)^{-1}$ and $dv = v'(x)dx = \cos(x) dx$, with

$$\int_{a}^{b} u(x)v'(x)dx = u(b)v(b) - u(a)v(a) - \int_{a}^{b} u'(x)v(x)dx \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: it's funny integration by parts was my first choice but i chose u=cosx which led me in a weird way... 
any tips on how to choose correctly? or is it mostly experience

Comment: @numbdigger It's experience to a certain extent. Also, since the choices are limited, if one way doesn't work, just try another way. However, in your particular case, I saw that there's no direct connection, in terms of derivatives and integrals, between $\cos x$ or $\sin x$, and $(x+1)^{-n}$ for $n = 1,2$. Since the LHS had $(1+x)^{-1}$ and the RHS had $(1 + x)^{-2}$, and I knew that with $u(x) = (1+x)^{-1}$ you get $u'(x) = -(1+x)^{-2}$, it seemed fairly clear that I wanted to differentiate that, i.e., have $u(x)$ as I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Use integration by parts (by taking $cosx$ as the second function) to get the following: 
$\int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{cosx}{1+x}dx =\frac{1}{1+x}sin x|_0^{\infty}+ \int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{sinx}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Answer (score 0):

Finding the antiderivative is not the best approach to the problem. Have you tried integration by parts with the following substitutions:

$$u = \frac{1}{1+x}$$

$$dv = \cos(x) \ dx$$

Of course, I'm going off of the general form of the formula for integration by parts:

$$\int u \ dv = uv - \int v \ du$$